# error importing gradle project into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

It´s my first time with gradle , I´m trying to import a gradle project into 
my Eclipse .

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
Build id: 20180619-1200
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_181

using import "Existing Gradle Project" ..I´m getting a error on the

org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-bin.zip'.

......
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'C:\WorkArea\os_temp\build.gradle' line: 14

line: 14 --> props.load(new FileInputStream("build.properties"))
....

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: build.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

the build.properties is there in the root folder of the project that I´m trying to import

this is the project that i´m trying to import
https://github.com/krishagni/openspecimen

thank you
Roque

Comment: You are three releases behind, [please upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades). With at least Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) you can even import broken Gradle projects (see [my video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aM3UUycl1rs&t=342s)).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issues for `gradle-5.3.1`, but while importing the project:

- I've changed "Local Installation Directory" to `C:\gradle-5.3.1`
- and "Gradle User Home" to the `C:\gradle-5.3.1\bin`
  and after this the project imported successfully, it solved my problem.

I hope this helps in your case.

[image: See my configure in pic]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this option during import
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Comment or temporarily remove the content in build.gradle file/files.
2. Delete .project and .classpath files in the folder you're importing (if any exists).
3. Override workspace settings and set it to Gradle wrapper
4. Specify Gradle user home (bin folder of gradle) and Java home jdk folder and click Next.
5. This solved my problem. If it doesn't work for you then try different options like setting `Local installation directory` for gradle and so on.
6. Once this works, you can put the content back to your build.gradle files and try again so that you know which line in build.gradle file causes the issue.

**Note**: The import might fail for other reasons as well which might need a different troubleshooting. This worked for me though.

[image]